# Check if a template group exists

Tags: templates, 404, template-scripting

Is there a way to check if a template group exists either in the templates or in a add-on?

For example, I would want to do something like this

```
{if {exp:foo:template_exists name="blog/test"} == "true"}
    {embed="bar/qux"}
{if:else}
    {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

Comment: If you have a blog/test template it will always exist so will always return true. Perhaps you can explain what you're trying to do as there's most likely another way of achieving it.

Comment: `{exp:foo:template_exists}` isn't really implemented. The reason why I was asking this question is to that I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm aware this functionality is built in by default, if there is no template then it'll automatically 404 error.

Please see the ExpressionEngine URL Schematic here:
http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/images/ExpressionEngine_url_schematic.png

Comment: What I wanted is some sort of function where I can pass a url, because I am going to use it in an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this is built in by default. [Have a look at this article by Jovia Web Studio](http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/) if you want to implement a more stringent 404 policy on your site. Comment are interesting as well.

Comment: I think he's trying to see if a template group other than the currently visited one exists. Basically, "Does that other page exist? If so, do this here on this page. If not, redirect this page as if it doesn't exist either."

Comment: @StephenCallender Yep, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do should be done using an Ajax function. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/template_group/',
    success: function() {
        alert('Page found.');
    },  
    error: function() {
        alert('Page not found.');
    }
});
```

If there's an error, redirect to your 404 page.